# Auto Complete / Code Sense on Doctrine Custom Repositories

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, autocomplete, phpstorm

I'm just discovering the awesome power of doctrine's custom repositories (especially when combined with traits). One thing that bugs me though is a lack of auto complete / code sense in PhpStorm.

For example, this is an endpoint in my Aye Aye controller. It gets the Artists entity, which uses a custom repository with the getFeatured method.

```php
public function getArtistsEndpoint($count = 10, $page = 0)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->getRepository('App\Entity\Artists')
                ->getFeatured($count, $page);
}
```

The problem is, `getFeatured()` doesn't come up in auto complete, nor does it allow me to click through to the method. It works perfectly, but from a maintenance point of view, if someone were to pick this up, they wouldn't easily be able to find the method. The only way I can think to do it is to break the chain like this:

```php
public function getArtistsEndpoint($count = 10, $page = 0)
{
    /** @var ArtistRepository $repository */
    $repository = $this->getEntityManager()
                       ->getRepository('App\Entity\Artists');
    return $repository->getFeatured($count, $page);
}
```

Is this the best/only way to do it, or is there something a little cleaner?

Comment: that or injecting the repo. or instiating the repo without doctrine (its been awhile since i messed with orms)